# How to store secret key used for hashing?

Tags: hash, key-management, salt

I am trying to figure out a secure way to store secret keys used in the hashing of social security numbers.

The idea is for de-identification of research subjects yet still permitting follow-ups over time by hashing a secret key concatenated with the SSN and using that as the unique identifier.

The steps I conceived of is the following:

1. At time 0, when data on subject A is collected, randomly generate a secret key and concatenate it with the SSN before hashing it.
2. Replace the SSN with the hash value. This de-identified record will be used for research purposes.
3. Store the SSN and generated secret key somehow.
4. At time 1, when further data of subject A is collected, we want to append this new data to the data collected previously. Search for the secret key using the SSN and then hashing again to get the required hash value.

I am struggling in Step 3 and looking for best practices in such a scenario. It seems that if I were to just store the SSN together with the secret key in a text file then the risk for reidentification is high once the intruder gets access of the file.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How would the hashing improve security? You could just generate (securely) a random number every time and use that as the new identifier - one less step to worry about. You still need to store the mapping from the SSN to the new identifier somewhere secure.

Comment: If you use a different secret key for hashing each SSN  then you could use the key instead of the SSN without the need  for hashing. The common way is to use a single  secret for all SSN instead and then you just need to limit access to this single secret. The efforts needed to protect this secret then depend on the actual requirements, but could also be done hardware-based with the help of a smart card or similar. Also note that what you are doing is not de-identification but only pseudonymization, i.e. given enough pseudonymized data it might still be possible to identify the subject.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I can’t do that because I still want to be able to identify the 2 data as belonging to the same person using some value, just that it is not via SSN. I thought that using a hash value instead would be good.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for pointing out the difference between de-identification and pseudonymizatiom. is there no added benefits in using a different key for each user? Also are there non-hardware based method in protecting the secret key?

Comment: @GAN: Again, if you have a single unpredictable secret per SSN then you don't need hashing the SSN but just use the key directly. With the same key instead for hashing many SSN you can instead concentrate of securing access to this (small) key. As I said, hardware based method is just one of several options to secure the key. To actually recommend a specific method one first need to know your requirements, i.e. a risk analysis of what kind of attacker you expect and how much risk you are willing to accept. The more capable an attacker is the harder (and more costly) the protection will be.

Comment: @GAN you would do that as often as you generate a secret key in your proposal - either once, or every time. If you generate it once, every replacement of the SSN results in the same value, but it also requires read/lookup access to the translation table during the replacement process.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I understand your point on using just the key directly. However I guess the same problem remains regarding how best to store the mapping of SSN to secret. But suppose I prefer the route of hashing using one secret key, are you able to list a few methods for me to read up on? Not asking you to suggest a specific method since I am unsure of the kind of attacks that can happen.

Comment: @GAN: just a few methods: since the key is short and can be easily typed in later you can print it out and store it in a safe. You can even split it and put the parts in multiple safes where different people have access. Or put in on USB-stick and put it in safe. Or encrypt the key so that a physical device like a smart card is needed to decrypt it. ...

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Also, are there guidelines on how long such a secret key should be?

Comment: @GAN: again, this depends on the still not existing risk analysis. But a 256 bit random (binary) key should probably be enough, even 128 bit for most cases.

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of is....

1) Use a lookup table to map SSNs to salts (or random identifiers for the persistent anonymized data) but keep this a long way away from the persistent, anonmyzed data. Both the datasets need to be compromised to resolve the data.

2) as per 1 but key the random value/random salt by a hash of the SSN (and keep the lookup table seperate). This adds some Security value over 1, but not a lot. Both datasets need to be compromized for the data to be resolved.

3) as per 2 but hash the SSN key using a static salt (i.e. storing hash($ssn, "staticsalt")->secret). Ideally keep the satic salt somewhere other than the 2 existing data stores. Once again this only adds a little Security value

4) use other information about the subject (if available) to increase the amount of entropy in the data used to create the hash. This would make it more difficult to deanonymize the data but doesn't impact the ability to find an individual in the dataset if their details are known.